# Enviar checkbox con ajax y php Mailer

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, phpmailer

Tengo el problema de cuando envío el formulario con checkbox a través de Ajax y PHP Mailer recibo el correo de la siguiente manera ¿Hay forma de nada más recibir los datos del checkbox? Saludos y gracias.

HTML - Esta es la parte del formulario

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    <span class="text-white">¿Cómo se enteró de nosotros?</span><br>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <label for="Google" class="form-check-label text-white">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="medio[]" id="medio" value="Google"> Google
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <label for="Redes Sociales" class="form-check-label text-white">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="medio[]" id="medio" value="Redes Sociales"> Redes Sociales (FB, Instagram, etc.)
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <label for="Representante" class="form-check-label text-white">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="medio[]" id="medio" value="Representante"> Representante
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <label for="Manejador" class="form-check-label text-white">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="medio[]" id="medio" value="Manejador"> Manejador
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <label for="Amigo" class="form-check-label text-white">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="medio[]" id="medio" value="Amigo"> Amigo
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <label for="Backstage" class="form-check-label text-white">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="medio[]" id="medio" value="Backstage"> Backstage
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <label for="Evento" class="form-check-label text-white">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="medio[]" id="medio" value="Evento"> Evento
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <label for="Otros" class="form-check-label text-white">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="medio[]" id="medio" value="Otros"> Otros
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

JS - Esta es la parte del JS con Ajax

```
function submitForm() {
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var tel = $("#tel").val();
    var medio = JSON.stringify($('[name="medio[]"]').serializeArray());
    var message = $("#message").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/contacto.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&tel=" + tel + "&medio=" + medio + "&message=" + message,
    success: function(text) {
        if (text == "success") {
            formSuccess();
        } else {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false, text);
        }
    }
});
```

}

PHP - Esta es la parte de PHP Mailer

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$tel = $_POST["tel"];
$medio = $_POST["medio"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$body = "";
$body .= "Nombre: ";
$body .= $name;
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "E-mail: ";
$body .= $email;
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "Teléfono: ";
$body .= $tel;
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "¿Cómo se enteró?: ";
$body .= $medio;
$body .= "<br>";
$body .= "Mensaje: ";
$body .= $message;
$body .= "<br>";
```

GRACIAAAAAAAAAAAAAS
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error, corrupti eius inventore saepe possimus. Illum nemo, qui natus, maxime officiis quos aliquam ea rem voluptates quae perferendis quia, animi eum.